# LazyColumn with items from viewModel crashes with IndexOutOfBounds when items size changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a LazyColumn where I am displaying items from my DB, items are based on selected date when date changes items size changes and then app crashes with IndexOutOfBoundException here is the code

getting items form viewModel

```
val allMedicines by viewModel.getMedicineByTime(selectedDateMillis).collectAsStateWithLifecycle(initialValue = emptyList())
```

and lazy column code is as follows

```
if (allMedicines.isEmpty()) {
    AnimateLottieRaw(resId = R.raw.empty_box, modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp))
    Text(
        text = "No Medicines scheduled for today\ntry adding some using the + button below",
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        fontFamily = dmSansFont,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    )
} else {
    LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        items(allMedicines) { medicine ->
            MedicineCard(medicine = medicine) {
                onEvent(ClickEvents.EditMedicine(it))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am facing this error only when lazyColumn needs to recompose if I make selected date constant and give a particular date then there is no issue but when I make it so that user clickEvent changes selected date it will crash, so please give me any solution or any hint

I have used some log statements to check if the list is getting updated and yes it's size is getting updated, I have tried to change lazyColumn to work with item size rather than actual list the code for that is as follows

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
     items(allMedicines.size) { pos ->
         val medicine = allMedicines[pos]
         MedicineCard(medicine = medicine) {
             onEvent(ClickEvents.EditMedicine(it))
         }
     }
}
```

but still not use

EDIT: I have replaced lazyColumn with a text and just displayed size of the items when date gets updated and it is working fine and displaying the items scheduled on that particualr date, so in my POV the issue here is not with the DB or the viewModel.

EDIT 2: for the time being I have removed the LazyColumn and replaced it with a normal column while iterating all Medicines manually, I know this isn't the way to do it but as a temporary measure, I had to do this, the code is as follows

```
Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().verticalScroll(rememberScrollState())) {
            allMedicines.forEach {
                MedicineCard(medicine = it) {
                    onEvent(ClickEvents.EditMedicine(it))
                }
            }
        }
```

this is just a temporary solution and it is working fine as of now so the issue here is with lazyColumn I guess, please let me know of any solution or at least any sort of hint that might lead to a better solution

[pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/FtWeS4sY) for the error log

Comment: hi, have you tried with watching the objects inside the allmedicines with a breakpoint.

Comment: can you please put the code where you set the data in allMedicines.

Comment: I am getting allMedicines from db through the viewModel which I have already included in the question or would you like me to share my MedicineRepository code it?

Comment: I have used already checked if allMedicines are getting updated and yes items are getting updated based on selected date also I have tried to remove lazyColumn and just display the size of allMedicines when date gets changed in a text and it works perfectly so the issue here is not with the items rather than lazyCoulmn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please update new version [1.6.0-beta01](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.6.0-beta01) of compose foundation if you are using verion [1.6.0-alpha08](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.6.0-alpha08) that exist [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/187188981) about the children of SubcomposeLayout.

Comment: thanks a lot man, updating dependency to beta worked for me, thanks a lot,

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that the list elements themselves and the `size` field of the list are not updated at the exact same time, so the list might already be shorter for a moment, but the size value still displays the old length, The `LazyColumn` then tries to display a position in your `allMedicines` list that actually does no longer exist, resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I suggest that if you need the index of the position of the item in the `LazyColumn`, use [`itemsIndexed`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/package-summary#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).itemsIndexed(kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function2,kotlin.Function3)) instead:

```
LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
     itemsIndexed(allMedicines) { index, medicine ->
         MedicineCard(medicine = medicine) {
             onEvent(ClickEvents.EditMedicine(index))
         }
     }
}
```

Note that the `items` function itself offers different parameters. The [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2)) mentions three variants:

- [`items` with providing a count](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#items(kotlin.Int,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2))
- [`items` with providing an Array](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).items(kotlin.Array,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2))
- [`items` with providing a List](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/lazy/LazyListScope#(androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyListScope).items(kotlin.collections.List,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function1,kotlin.Function2))

---

**Edit**: As the answer below suggests, there is a bug in Jetpack Compose. It has been reported in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308840227), recently [fixed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2788274) and published with Compose Foundation Version 1.6.0-beta01. You can include it with the following dependency:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.0-beta01")
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply but still I am facing the same issue indexOutOfBound

Comment: I have pasted the error log in pastebin if interested check it out https://pastebin.com/FtWeS4sY

Comment: I cannot open pastebin links right now, maybe you can copy the stacktrace as code into your post? My guess however is that the crash is coming from some other place. You also can outcomment the `onEvent(...)` statement and see if the issue persists.