# IndexOutOfBoundsException when removing item from LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am getting an IndexOutOfBoundsException when I remove an item from a list in a LazyColumn in Jetpack Compose. The following code reproduces the error:

```
val list = remember { mutableStateListOf(1, 2, 3) }

LazyColumn {
    itemsIndexed(list) { index, value ->
        Button(onClick = {
            list.removeAt(index)
        }) { Text(value.toString()) }
    }
}
```

The error occurs when I click the button to remove the item. If I use list.clear() or add an item to the list, the error does not occur.

I have tried `itemsIndexed(list) { index, value ->` instead and some oher variations.
None of these solutions have worked.

Any suggestions?

Additional details:

- I am using `id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.20"`
- I am using `kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4"`
- I am using Jetpack Compose `implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))`.
- I am using Material3 `implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha11")`
- I am targeting SDK Version 34.

Thanks!

Comment: Could [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74134219/jetpack-compose-lazycolumn-not-updating-with-mutablelist) help?

Comment: `val list = SnapshotStateList<Int>()`

same error with SnapshotStateList

Comment: This is expected error since you are not using any kind of iterator. Modifying list while iterating through it in `for` loop is dangerous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There recently was a similar [StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77450619/8331157), and as it turns out, it is a bug in Jetpack Compose. This bug was already reported at the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/308840227) and [fixed](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2788274). The fix should be present in the latest release of the Compose Foundation Library, so you need to override your BOM dependency definition:

```
dependencies {
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.10.01"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha11")
    // use 1.6.0-beta01
    implementation("androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.6.0-beta01")
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, with this version it works as expected.